# Don't understand the 'AND' after the 'ON' clause in an ANSI SQL inner join syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I have a query that joins on one table. 
I totally understand the inner join on company_no. And even if there was another join condition with an **`=`** sign, I would have understood. But what is the greater than or equal to right after the ON clause `AND ts.trans_date >= mtd.trans_date`? I am not able to comprehend what this is doing.

```
SELECT  ts.trans_date, ts.company_no, ts.transactions, ts.mtd_transactions, SUM(mtd.transactions) AS tabulated_mtd_transactions
FROM    transactions_tbl ts
    INNER JOIN transactions_tbl mtd
    ON  ts.company_no = mtd.company_no
    AND ts.trans_date >= mtd.trans_date
        WHERE   ts.company_no = 1080 
                    AND ts.trans_date >= '2010-08-01'
            AND mtd.trans_date >= '2010-08-01'
GROUP BY    ts.trans_date, ts.company_no, ts.transactions, ts.mtd_transactions
ORDER BY    ts.trans_date
```

Comment: Your formatting might be confusing you. I would put the WHERE statement at the left-hand margin, because it's not part of the FROM or JOIN clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query tries to build a running sum of `transaction` for a certain company.

Basically, it takes every record in `transactions_tbl` for that company starting with `2010-08-01`, joins it to all records earlier than that (and still later than `2010-08-01`) in the same table for the same company, and finds the sum of those records.

Since PostgreSQL 8.4 and Oracle 8i, there is a more efficient method to do that:

```
SELECT  *,
        SUM(transactions) OVER (PARTITION BY company_no ORDER BY trans_date)
FROM    transactions_tbl
WHERE   ts.company_no = 1080
        AND ts.trans_date >= '2010-08-01'
ORDER BY
        trans_date
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the OVER clause?

Comment: I sort of understand what you mean. But when you mentioned, `joins it to all records earlier than that (and still later than 2010-08-01) in the same table for the same company, and finds the sum of those records.`  Wont that cause cartesian product.

Comment: @user2081579 `SUM(...) OVER (...)` is an aggregate being used as a *window function*. See the [PostgreSQL documentation on window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) to learn more.

Comment: @user2081579: actually half of the cartesian product, but it's the same `O(n^2)` in terms of O big notation, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

The "inner join" in your query is equivalent to a cross product of the two tables and then a selection on the result with the where clause being the predicate in the ON section of the inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do explicit INNER JOIN statements for some reason?

```
SELECT  ts.trans_date, ts.company_no, ts.transactions, ts.mtd_transactions, SUM(mtd.transactions) AS tabulated_mtd_transactions
FROM    transactions_tbl ts, transactions_tbl mtd
WHERE
    ts.company_no = mtd.company_no
    AND ts.trans_date >= mtd.trans_date
    AND ts.company_no = 1080 
    AND ts.trans_date >= '2010-08-01'
    AND mtd.trans_date >= '2010-08-01'
GROUP BY    ts.trans_date, ts.company_no, ts.transactions, ts.mtd_transactions
ORDER BY    ts.trans_date
```

That should be the same as your statement without the confusion of explicit INNER JOIN statements.

If you really wanted to clean things up...

```
SELECT  ts.trans_date, ts.company_no, ts.transactions, ts.mtd_transactions, SUM(ts.transactions) AS tabulated_mtd_transactions
FROM    transactions_tbl ts
WHERE ts.company_no = 1080 
AND ts.trans_date >= '2010-08-01'
GROUP BY    ts.trans_date, ts.company_no, ts.transactions, ts.mtd_transactions
ORDER BY    ts.trans_date
```

I think that should work so long as `ts.trans_date >= mtd.trans_date` was a mistake.

Comment: I am learning how to use the ANSI syntax. I want to use the INNER JOIN.

Comment: Explicit inner join statements are typically preferred because they're easier to understand, by virtue of being... more explicit.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I have always found them to be inherently confusing because they take a simple concept of merging based on specific columns and clutter the SQL... e.g. http://pastebin.com/qZZcqRUV

Comment: No, implicit joins mix the simple concept of joining with the simple concept of filtering into a single (confusing) expression.